# Trying to figure out the average of existing objects in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, average

I need help trying to figure out the average pay for each Associate.
Here is the code I currently have.

```
class Associate:
    ID = 0;
    avgPay = 0.0

    def __init__(self, ID, name, pay):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.pay = pay
        Associate.ID += 1
        Associate.avgPay = (pay + Associate.avgPay)/Associate.ID

    def speak(self):
        print('Name: ', self.name,'Pay: ', self.pay )

a1 = Associate('A111','Emily',85000)
a1.speak()
print("ID = {0}, avgPay = {1}".format(Associate.ID,Associate.avgPay))
a2 = Associate('A222','Bob',88000)
a2.speak()
print("ID = {0}, avgPay = {1}".format(Associate.ID,Associate.avgPay))
a3 = Associate('A333','John',92000)
a3.speak()
print("ID = {0}, avgPay = {1}".format(Associate.ID,Associate.avgPay))
a4 = Associate('A444','Tom',77000)
a4.speak()
print("ID = {0}, avgPay = {1}".format(Associate.ID,Associate.avgPay))
```

My problem is that every time it calls `Associate.avgPay` it will add up the average from the previous call instead of adding `self.pay`.
Current Output:

```
Name: Emily Pay:  85000
ID = 1, avgPay = 85000.0
Name: Bob Pay:  88000
ID = 2, avgPay = 86500.0
Name: John Pay:  92000
ID = 3, avgPay = 59500.0
Name: Tom Pay:  77000
ID = 4, avgPay = 34125.0
```

Correct output:

```
Name: Emily Pay:  85000
ID = 1, avgPay = 85000.0
Name: Bob Pay:  88000
ID = 2, avgPay = 86500.0
Name: John Pay:  92000
ID = 3, avgPay = 88333.33333
Name: Tom Pay:  77000
ID = 4, avgPay = 85500.0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Averages don't work like that. You need a list of all pays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrote the average algorithm you tried on paper for more than two objects, you'd see that you aren't actually calculating an average.

You need to sum all the values at once, then divide, not add new values to an already divided value, and divide again...

Also, the fact that you're repeating code means that you should really consider using a list anyway. Also don't need any class attributes

Here's such an example

```
associates = [] 
associates.append(Associate('A111','Emily',85000))
associates.append(Associate('A222','Bob',88000)) 
associates.append(Associate('A333','John',92000)) 
associates.append(Associate('A444','Tom',77000)) 

pays = [a.pay for a in associates] 
avg = sum(pays)/len(pays) 
for id, a in enumerate(associates):
    a.speak()
    print("ID = {0}, avgPay = {1}".format(id, avg))
```

Answer (score 0):

Average calculation seems wrong, at least.
It should be,

```
Associate.avgPay = (pay + Associate.avgPay * (Associate.ID-1))/Associate.ID
```

Comment: Are you multiplying to cancel the previous division?

Comment: Roughly, yes. Numerator needs to be a total sum of past pays.

Comment: Still seems wrong since you'd also need to subtract off the previous pay before multiplying

Comment: Hmm...I'm afraid but did you actually try it? At least, the modified equation outputs true average values for given values.

Answer (score 0):

As @cricket_007 said, averages *don't* work that way. What you could do is keep track of all the payments in a list and use that to calculate the average:

```
class Associate:
    ID = 0;
    payList = []

    def __init__(self, ID, name, pay):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.pay = pay
        Associate.ID += 1
        Associate.payList.append(pay)
        Associate.avgPay = sum(Associate.payList) / len(Associate.payList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a running total of aggregate pay as an additional class attribute if you do not want to keep a list:

```
class Associate:
    ID = 0;
    avgPay = 0.0
    totalPay = 0.0

    def __init__(self, ID, name, pay):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.pay = pay
        Associate.totalPay+=pay
        Associate.ID += 1
        Associate.avgPay = Associate.totalPay / Associate.ID

    def speak(self):
        print('Name: ', self.name,'Pay: ', self.pay )
```

Then your series of objects work as you intend:

```
a1 = Associate('A111','Emily',85000)
a1.speak()
print("ID = {0}, avgPay = {1}".format(Associate.ID,Associate.avgPay))
a2 = Associate('A222','Bob',88000)
a2.speak()
print("ID = {0}, avgPay = {1}".format(Associate.ID,Associate.avgPay))
a3 = Associate('A333','John',92000)
a3.speak()
print("ID = {0}, avgPay = {1}".format(Associate.ID,Associate.avgPay))
a4 = Associate('A444','Tom',77000)
a4.speak()
print("ID = {0}, avgPay = {1}".format(Associate.ID,Associate.avgPay))
```

Prints:

```
Name:  Emily Pay:  85000
ID = 1, avgPay = 85000.0
Name:  Bob Pay:  88000
ID = 2, avgPay = 86500.0
Name:  John Pay:  92000
ID = 3, avgPay = 88333.33333333333
Name:  Tom Pay:  77000
ID = 4, avgPay = 85500.0
```